# Modify class property from byref passed function parameter inside of function

Tags: vb.net, class, pass-by-reference

I understand my issue at hand but am looking for a recommended work around.

I have a class which contains a get/set property and when the set is called with a specific value it will perform some action.

```
Public Class A
  Private _bFlag As Boolean

  Public Property bFlag() As Boolean
     Get
        Return _bFlag
     End Get
     Set(value As Boolean)
        _bFlag = value
        If (value) Then
           ...do something...
        End If
     End Set
  End Property

End Class
```

When I pass the class variable as ByRef to a local routine, the Set property is not triggered until after the function completes.  But I have some transient action performed where the flag is toggled.  I would like to be notified of the variable toggle immediately.

```
...
Dim myClassA as New A
...
<------Here the bFlag is False
Func1(myClassA.bFlag)
<------Here the bFlag is False since Func1 completed with the bFlag set as False
<------ the Set was never called since the variable never changed at this level

Public Sub Func1(ByRef flag as Boolean)
   ... start some action
   flag = True
   ... stop some action
   flag = False
End Sub
```

I understand this is the expected action from this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2010/01/26/the-many-cases-of-byref.aspx) which contains example:

```
Sub CopyBackByRef_Explained()
    Dim v1 = New C1
    Dim vbTemp = v1.P1
    FunctionWithInt(vbTemp)
    v1.P1 = vbTemp
End Sub
```

where the variables passed by reference are first made a temp copy to pass in function.

How can I make it so I can get immediate notification on the change of the variable passed ByRef?

Comment: `How can ... get immediate notification` do you mean in runtime code or in the IDE? Having a property setter DO something meaningful beyond validation is usually a bad idea.  Consider a method instead.

Comment: Is there a reason you have to pass it BYREF?

Comment: @Plutonix runtime code

Comment: @Steve Since the variable was being modified inside and I wanted to save any change even after function completes

Comment: When you pass a complex object, like a class, byval, a pointer to the original object is passed which means changes to the object within the method effect the original object. When you pass a complex object byref, it must make a copy of the object to send back when the method ends. This is why your not getting the property 'setter' to fire until the method completes. Passing your class byval will get you what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could pass the property as a lambda expression and use reflection to call the setter, but it's probably easier to just wrap the setter call in a lambda and pass that in:

```
Func1(Sub(value) myClassA.bFlag = value)

Public Sub Func1(flag As Action(Of Boolean))
    ' start some action
    flag(True)
    ' stop some action
    flag(False)
End Sub
```